# Chrome "Create application shortcuts" Shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there an extension for Chrome which will launch the current website in a new browser window with no toolbar and associate it with the website's custom icon, very similar to what happens when you click the "Create application shortcuts" option from the Tools menu?

Reason for asking this is there are a few websites I use which require authentication on a separate site first, which then launch the web application in a new window. When making the authentication site an application, the desired site appears in a regular Chrome browser thus defeating the point.

One way this could be done is through launching `chrome.exe` with the current URL and the other parameters required to launch such applications. However I'm not sure if this is possible via a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There couldn’t be an extension like that because extensions are supposed to be secured as much as possible, and what you want would require unfettered access to your system (especially the file system). Extensions only have limited access to write to local files, and even then, only in the designated places, not wherever they want.

What you want would have to be built into Chrome. You could *attempt* to [request such a feature](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), however certainly don’t expect the part about the lack of a toolbar to be implemented.

Failing that, you could try simply creating a shortcut, setting the target to the URL of the destination site (not the auth site), and download the site’s icon and set that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - it gave me the idea to write an AutoHotKey script to do the job. Copy the page URL into the clipboard, then launch chrome.exe with the URL using the --app parameter. Works well enough. The script also preserves the original clipboard contents. Can be downloaded here if interested [link]http://dl.dropbox.com/u/945683/launchchromeapp.ahk

Comment: Nice work-around. `:-)`

Comment: link is dead, would be nice if you'd make it available again!

Comment: @stian, the link I posted to Chrome’s bug-tracker is fine. Are you talking about the link that user81021 posted? If so, then you should address them specifically (`@user81021 …`), otherwise they won’t get notified of your comment. Of course they [don’t have much activity here](http://superuser.com/users/81021/user81021) and have not been around for a month, so you may want to try [Googling for it](http://www.google.com/search?q=launch+chrome+app+ahk) (or an alternative) in the meantime.

Comment: yes, I meant the link that @user81021 posted. Thanks for the tip regarding notification. I'll try to find some time to learn AHK and set it up myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to be available via Google, and I never download the file so you may indeed have to recreate it—it’s not very complex and learning AHK is well worth it. ☺